# how to get class/id name from template (django) on post

Tags: django, post, request

I need to get the id of the object clicked so I can use it in a query in the view.

*template*

```
<form action="/services/delpoll/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
       <td><input type="submit" id="{{b.id}}" class="delete_poll" value="Borrar"></td>
     </form>
```

*view*

```
def delpoll(request):

    connect_mysql = mdb.connect('*', '*', '*', '*')
    cursorMYSQL = connect_mysql.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        id_poll = request.POST.get['delete_poll'];
        cursorMYSQL.execute(""" delete from snmptt_listpolls where id='%s' """%(id_poll))

        connect_mysql.commit()
        connect_mysql.close()

        return render_to_response("delpoll.html",{"message": 'post'} ) 

    else:

        return render_to_response("delpoll.html",{"message": 'no-post'} )
```

Comment: What value is coming id_poll?

Comment: It's declare there, I want to save in that variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
<button type="submit" value="{{b.id}}" name="id_value" class"delete_poll">Borrar</button>
```

**Then in a view:**

```
request.POST.get("id_value", "")
```

Read this can help you too. [Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects)

Comment: I tried it and in the variable it saves the value, which means, "Borrar".

Comment: change the value to {{b.id}}

Comment: If I change the value it will be shown and I want all the buttons to have "Borrar" in it

Comment: <button type="submit" value="{{b.id}}" name="id_value" class"delete_poll">Borrar</button>